# A delegate accepting zero, one or more parameters

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, delegates

Within C#, is it possible to declare a delegate in such a way that it accepts zero, one, or multiple parameters? Is the `dynamic` keyword going to help

In other words if I have a bunch of functions which I add to this delegate, is it possible to determine, based on number and types of parameters, which of these functions to call, when the delegate gets called?

Comment: The idea of combining multiple functions in a single delegate is that all of them get called. Why would you _not_ want to use different delegates here?

Comment: It is generally not possible. What if the signature of two of your functions is identical? You would need to identify the functions differently. But then there is no point in going through that hassle, just because you are trying to solve the problem with *one* delegate.

Comment: This is not what delegates are for.

Comment: I agree with others say that it is not a good design pattern or idea, but you might want to try using 'params object[] objects' as your delegate signature.

Comment: For consumer of that code it's very unclear without extensive documentation as to what the method expects for parameters. Not to mention it's not type safe.

Answer (score 3):

From the MSDN Documentation:

> Any method that matches the delegate's signature, which consists of
>   the return type and parameters, can be assigned to the delegate.

The very concept of dynamic delegate parameters would conflict with this definition. 
So no you cannot have a delegate accepting multiple signatures.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear how you're gonna generalize the functions call chain with different parameters count, type and return type (as much as I understood). Definitely the `delegate` is not your friend here.

What you need to do, imo, is:

Define a custom class where you can aggregate the functions you need and call them iteration over the list,queue or whatever. If you want use a `delegates` you need to define a single delegate for *every* type of the function. This is actually goodness of `delegates`: type-safe function pointers.